# How to split string at regular intervals in Python 3

Tags: python, string, intervals

I need to split a string at a regular interval and return a string with the same characters (one space and letters) with newlines at each interval so it gets to represent some kind of row/column rectangular-shaped string. I needs to return something as follows (example):

```
>>> s = 'sliding puzzles'
>>> puzzle(s, 3, 5)
'slidi
ng pu
zzles'
```

Anyone?

Comment: This sounds like a pretty simple exercise. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm unsure if i understand your requirment. You wan't a function puzzle that takes a string and 2 ints. In you example the string should be splitted at 5 chars..what's the 3 i.e. the 1st int for ?

Comment: I'm not really stuck, but I need my focus elsewhere. 3 stands for rows and 5 for columns. Needed in a bigger programme. Call it a blackout I'm experiencing at this regard.

Comment: What would be the expected output for `puzzle(s, 3, 6)`?

Comment: Whatever you downvoters. Snobs.

Comment: Well, I'm sure I can handle it. I just need to write a programme that can simulate a sliding puzzle. For it I need to make a separate class called sliding_puzzle on which I can use the function slide which gives in the command in which direction to slide a symbol to empty space in the rectangle (the white space in the string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

```
def puzzle(s,a,b):
    if a*b != len(s):
       print "Not possible"
       return
    start =0
    end = b+1
    output =""
    for i in range(0,a):
        output= output+s[start: end]+"\n"
        start = end+1
        end = end+b
    print output
```

Comment: Thanks I can use this. Anyway, the reason I'm asking this seemingly simple (yet specific and small) question so I can solve the bigger task before a certain deadline and so I can focus more on other of my obligations outside of the sphere of programming.
Thanks again. This really helps.

Comment: Yours is close, but not there. After the first row it replaces the letter with a newline rather than interjecting it. But I drew inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Thanks to Bhavish Agarwal.

```
def puzzle(s, r, c):
assert r*c == len(s), 'not possible'
start = 0
end = c
output =""
for _ in range(0, r - 1):
    output= output+s[start: end]+"\n"
    start = end
    end = end + c
output= output+s[start: end]
return output
```

And that's how easy it is. Thanks for the swift response. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using join to get your newlines in, and a list comprehension to do the splitting:

```
def make_slice(my_str, slice_length, slice_start):
    return mystr[slice_length * slice_start:slice_length * (slice_start + 1)]

def puzzle(my_string, substring_length):
    return '\n'.join([make_slice(my_string, substring_length, substring_index)
                      for substring_index 
                      in range((len(my_string) // substring_length) + 1)])
```

This variant doesn't require specifying the height of the puzzle, just the length of the substring.  The last line of the puzzle may need to be space-padded to reach the same length as the other lines.